# no puedo aplicar Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Estoy aprendiendo React JS y tengo problemas en poder usar estilos de libreria MAterial UI

instale segun la pagina:

```
npm install @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc styled-components
```

aunque cuando quiero usar un boton, no lo puedo ver correcto. Se ve el contorno del boton, pero no el texto dentro de el, ni el color que deberia estar. a alguien le paso?

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
<Button variant="contained">Contained</Button>
```

Comment: Podría mostrar su código completo que tiene en su archivo? para facilitar la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si el codigo que tienes del Button es asi tal cual como lo muestras, te faltaria rendelizarlo y eso se hace siempre dentro de un **render** (si es un class component) o dentro de un **return** (si es un componente funcional)  como se muestra aqui abajo:

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

function App() { 
  return (
    <Button variant="contained"> Contained </Button>
  )
 }
```